# Grails 3.1.6 : build failed for grails war for gradle 2.6

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.1

I have multiproject structure which I migrated from 3.1.4 to 3.1.6

My mac machine has following environment
gradle -version 2.9
| Grails Version: 3.1.6
| Groovy Version: 2.4.6
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_60-ea

When I try to assemble app using
grails war

Both throws error for gradle jar 2.6

I already did following

- Checked gradle wrapper version its 2.9
- I already did clean on my projects but no help
- sh gradlew war (works)
- sh gradlew assemble (works)
- grails war (failed)

## Error stack for grails war

```
| Error Command [war] error: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-bin.zip'. (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:72)
    at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_runBuildWithConsoleOutput_closure5.doCall(GradleUtil.groovy:122)
    at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_withProjectConnection_closure3.doCall(GradleUtil.groovy:102)
    at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_withProjectConnection_closure3.call(GradleUtil.groovy)
    at grails.io.support.SystemOutErrCapturer.withNullOutput(SystemOutErrCapturer.groovy:64)
    at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil.withProjectConnection(GradleUtil.groovy:101)
    at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil.runBuildWithConsoleOutput(GradleUtil.groovy:117)
    at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleInvoker.invokeMethod(GradleInvoker.groovy:50)
    at assemble.run(assemble.groovy:19)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.script.GroovyScriptCommand.handle(GroovyScriptCommand.groovy:152)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:452)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:372)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:345)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:274)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:162)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(Ljava/util/List;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:105)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:102)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(Ljava/util/List;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Ljava/util/List;
    at asset.pipeline.gradle.AssetCompile.getSource(AssetCompile.groovy:188)
    at asset.pipeline.gradle.AssetCompile_Decorated.getSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo$4.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:460)
    at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo.getValue(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:458)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$Validator$1.call(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:262)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext$BuildableFileTreeInternalConverter.convertInto(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileCollections(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsBuildables(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.addDependencies(CompositeFileCollection.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$3.resolve(CompositeFileCollection.java:124)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:112)
    at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.doResolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:53)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.realizedDependencies(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:181)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:138)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.addTasks(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:144)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:103)
    ... 42 more
| Error Command [war] error: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-bin.zip'.
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample project which demonstrates the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the exact same problem. Found that gradle version upgrade to 2.9 or higher will fix the issue.

or directly use gradle to build the war

> ```
> ./gradlew clean assemble
> ```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38633960/5330223) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37180358/5330223) for more details.

Late but hope it helps someone.