# Grails 3 error when packaging aplication- Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':gspCompile'

Tags: java, servlets, grails, grails-3.1

App Info:

- Grails Version: 3.1.8
- Groovy Version: 2.4.6
- JVM Version:
  1.8.0_60

I'm running `grails package` to get runnable archives however I come across the following error:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':gspCompile'.
>   Could not resolve javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0.
>     Required by:
>         app:app:0.1
>   Could not resolve javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.pom'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.pom'.
>   Connect to repo.grails.org:443 [repo.grails.org/52.205.225.191, repo.grails.org/23.23.24.228] failed: Connection timed out: connect

```
Error Command [package] error: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-bin.zip'.
```

The servlet api is in fact in the grails repo (thanks to Loucher) so I'm not entirely sure why I'm gettin this error.

Comment: i've just checked `https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/` and `3.1.0` is there with required pom

Comment: You are right. It is there. Not sure why my app is not picking it up. I shall investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I have found out that Grails 3 should use [Gradle 2.2 or higher](http://www.mscharhag.com/grails/whats-new-in-grails-3) and I was using version 2.1.3. After changing my gradle version to 2.3 the error seems to have disappeared however I had not got my runnable archives due to other errors. The error I was getting was the following:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(Ljava/util/List;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Ljava/util/List;
```

After searching this error I had encountered I found out there is a [bug](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9923) in grails. More searching lead me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983466/cannot-package-grails-3-appplication-nosuchmethoderror). I updated my Gradle version to 2.9 as suggested in the comments using the command below:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 2.9
```

I then used gradle to generate the war file and thankfully that seemed to have done it.